# How to configure the datasource for the Kendo Treeview?

Tags: datasource, kendo-treeview

This should be an easy one but I'm missing something. I have an MVC application that returns JSON data using this controller method:

```
    public ActionResult GetVenues()
    {
        ActionResult ar = Json(_VenueRepository.GetData(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return ar;
    }
```

Nothing fancy here. I'm displaying a Kendo treeview on my view using the following code:

```
var venuetree = function () {
    $("#venuetreeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataSource: [{ id: 0, text: "Venues", items: [{ id: 1, text: "Venue 1", items: [{ id: 5, text: "Venue 2" }] }, { id: 2, text: "Venue 3", items: [{ id: 14, text: "Venue 4" }] }, { id: 3, text: "Venue 5", items: [{ id: 38, text: "Venue 6" }, { id: 39, text: "Venue 7" }, { id: 25, text: "Venue 8" }, { id: 26, text: "Venue 9" }, { id: 27, text: "Venue 10" }, { id: 28, text: "Venue 11" }] }, { id: 30, text: "Venue 12" }, { id: 40, text: "Venue 13", items: [{ id: 41, text: "Venue 14" }] }, { id: 4, text: "Venue 15", items: [{ id: 29, text: "Venue 16" }] }, { id: 31, text: "Venue 17" }, { id: 32, text: "Venue 18" }] }]

        //dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        //    transport: {
        //        read: {
        //            url: "DataManager/GetVenues",
        //            dataType: "json",
        //            contentType: "application/json"
        //        }
        //    },
        //    pageSize: 100,
        //    requestEnd: function (e) {
        //        $("#wait").hide();
        //    },
        //})
    }).data("kendoTreeView");
};
```

The hard-coded JSON here renders just fine. I obtained this JSON directly from the ActionResult object in the controller method.

However, when I uncomment the code that returns the HierarchicalDataSource (while commenting out the hard-coded version, of course) The treeview displays a *Loading* message with a wait animation. Note: same problem using DataSource as HierarchicalDataSource.

Any ideas why its acting this way?

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 0):

i use this

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ 
      transport: {
          read: {
           url: foo,
           datatype: "json",
           contentType: "application/json"
          }
         
      },
      schema: {
          model: {
              children: "items",
              id: "id"
          },
          data: function(data) {
              var dataArray = eval(data);
              return dataArray;
          }
      }
  });
```

I think eval(data) is the solution.
I tried many things and after using eval it works :)